# Cannot set per-user limit for google maps and places api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to set **per user API request limit** for my android app, which utilizes **Maps API** and **Places API**. But this is the screen I get. There is no input field. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you managed to solve this, it is happening to me now!

Comment: Nope, it seems to be a bug that no one has yet noticed. Strange...